# PPPOE Config not working

Tags: cisco, pppoe

I have a Cisco 881-W router with Cisco IOS C880 Version 12.4(24)T5.

For some reason I can't seem to get an IP on the Dialer. I'm probably doing something stupid wrong.

```
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
Dialer1                    unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up
FastEthernet0              unassigned      YES unset  up                    down
FastEthernet1              unassigned      YES unset  up                    down
FastEthernet2              unassigned      YES unset  up                    down
FastEthernet3              unassigned      YES unset  up                    down
FastEthernet4              unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up
NVI0                       unassigned      NO  unset  up                    up
Vlan1                      unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up
Wlan-GigabitEthernet0      unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
wlan-ap0                   unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up


interface fastEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 pppoe enable group global
 pppoe-client dial-pool-number 1
 no cdp enable

interface fastEthernet0/1
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 no cdp enable

interface Dialer0
 ip address negotiated
 ip mtu 1492
 ip flow ingress
 ip nat outside
 encapsulation ppp
 dialer pool 1
 ppp authentication pap callin
 ppp pap sent-username --- password ---
 ppp ipcp dns request accept
 ppp ipcp route default
 ppp ipcp address accept
 no cdp enable
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that the dialer interface gets triggered by "interesting traffic"

According to ...

https://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/routers/access/800/850/software/configuration/guide/pppoenat.html

... you need a dialer list/dialer-group statement with that.

```
dialer-list 144 protocol ip permit

[...]

interface dialer 0 
 dialer-group 144
```

Hint:

If anyhow possible, stay away from the "1" numbers for dialer pools and dialer lists, even more so when access list numbers come into play ("access list 1 permit ...") on top of that.

It makes the configuration confusing to read, especially to the novice.

I have no clue why Cisco's examples and documentation stick to that numbering style. By all means, do prefer named items (e.g. in ACLs) or pick "random" numbers that can easily be matched by a human reader, even when they're dozens or hundreds of lines away from each other in a config file.

Comment: Thanks, I now got the Dialer an IP but I don't know by god how to continue from here. I'll try creating a NAT I think.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. The `dialer0` Interface will be your `nat outside` and (since you said it was a Cisco 880) an SVI (`interface vlan XX`) will be your `nat inside` interface. At least one port of the integrated 4port-switch should be set to `switchport mode acccess` and `switchport access vlan XX`, and `spanning-tree portfast`. Having some sort of DHCP service on the internal LAN might also help (can be done by the 880, too).  
Then start with adding a general NAT overload rule like `ip nat inside source list <ACL-covering-your-internal-IPspace> interface dialer0 overload` .

Comment: First, check if the default route is present, once the PPPoE session is established and the Dialer0 interface is _up_   (do a `show ip route` and look for an entry of 0.0.0.0/0).
There should be an entry similar to  `S*    0.0.0.0/0 [10/0] via 83.79.130.1, Dialer0` . The IP address at "via" could be missing (and will be different from this example), but it _must_ have `Dialer0` as egress interface.